# Use of stack pointer (sp) in arm assembly

Tags: ios, assembly, stack, arm, disassembly

I'm slightly confused by the following bit of disassembly:

```
_GSEventLockDevice:
000047d8        b5f0    push    {r4, r5, r6, r7, lr}
000047da        af03    add r7, sp, #12
000047dc        b08d    sub sp, #52
000047de    f7ffffb3    bl  _GSGetPurpleSystemEventPort
000047e2        466d    mov r5, sp
000047e4        2234    movs    r2, #52
000047e6        2100    movs    r1, #0
000047e8        4604    mov r4, r0
000047ea        4628    mov r0, r5
000047ec    f005e8b0    blx 0x9950  @ symbol stub for: _memset
000047f0        2600    movs    r6, #0
000047f2    f24030f6    movw    r0, 0x3f6
000047f6        4621    mov r1, r4
000047f8    e88d0041    stmia.w sp, {r0, r6}
000047fc        4628    mov r0, r5
000047fe    f7fffaf7    bl  _GSSendEvent
00004802        b00d    add sp, #52
00004804        bdf0    pop {r4, r5, r6, r7, pc}
00004806        bf00    nop
```

I don't get how this would go in C. The only bit I get is:

```
memset(whateverTheStackPointerIs, 0, 52);
```

But how do I know what sp is and how would it look in C?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The

```
sub sp, #52
```

reserves 52 bytes of space for local variables on the stack; afterwards `sp` will point to the first of those 52 bytes. They are all then zeroed with the memset call. After the memset, `stmia` stores particular values in the first two words. So the C equivalent would be something like

```
GEEventLockDecvice() {
    int tmp = GSGetPurpleSystemEventPort();
    int localdata[13] = {0};
    localdata[0] = *0x3f6;
    localdata[1] = 0;
    return GSSendEvent(&localdata, tmp);
}
```

Comment: +1 looks pretty faithful. `*0x3f6` isn't legal C though. I think in this case it should be `*(volatile uint16_t*)0x3f6`. Or is it loading 32-bit values, then `uint32_t`.

Comment: I think `.w` on ARM means 32 bits. 16 bits would be "halfword" in ARM lingo.

Comment: When would you use the stack over registers?

Comment: When you don't have enough registers to hold everything. Or when, as here, you're calling something that wants a pointer to your data. You can't have a pointer to registers.

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly. But when declaring GSSendEvent, how can I get it to accept the int array pointer? I tried  void GSSendEvent(int *data, mach_port_t port) but that didn't work. As a temporary solution I just have  void GSSendEvent(...)

Comment: As a matter of C semantics, the `&localdata` produces a "pointer to array of int", not just a "pointer to int". That's not important for understanding the assembler. Bear in mind that I'm not sure it's actually an int array in the first place. Probably it's a structure of some kind; it's impossible to tell from the assembly. Try googling `GSSendEvent`.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Got it all sorted. But what's with the third line (second line of assembly) where r7 is assigned to the stack pointer + 12. I don't see where that's ever used and seems slightly pointless

Comment: Yes, that looks pointless. Apparently (as far as I can google up) r7 is used to optimize local-variable access in some thumb instructions. Possibly the compiler is just initializing it on general principles, and is not smart enough to notice that it is not actually using it.

Comment: Note that this thumb2 code not ARM code.  ARM the company yes, the ARM flavor of instruction set no.  thumb2 is part thumb with thumb2 extensions.  32 bit instructions like the movw are thumb2 instructions.  the exception being there are some 32 bit branch instructions in thumb.  ARM (the company) defines a word as 32 bit, halfword as 16 bits.  mov rd,#immed, encoding T1, gives 8 bits of immediate, T2 mov.w rd,#const 12 bits of immediate giving some intersting 32 bit combinations, T3 movw rd,#imm16 gives 16 bits of immediate, 0x3F6 would and does here fall into the T3 encoding

Comment: infocenter.arm.com down the left ARM architecture, click on reference manuals and then probably the ARMv7-M to get the thumb/thumb2 instruction set (and other thumb2 info).